# Cannot get Vimeo <iframe> embed code working in IE7/8/9

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, embed, vimeo

I am using this code from Vimeo to embed a player on a website:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/44327600" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

The player appears with image preview, and functions correctly in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

It does not work on IE9 standalone, or IE8 or IE7 using [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). I am on 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate

I had the code embedded within a lightbox firing when the "Watch Presentation" button is clicked, which you can also test on the URL below. To test, I've isolated the code separately beneath the three buttons -- where it still is not working.

Has anyone had any problems with this new-ish embed method from Vimeo? Any ideas or suggestions greatly welcomed, I'm about at my wits end here :}

Here is a link to the page: http://cme.stage.setsailmedia.com/cme/cme/?y=1

Comment: I've opened a support thread on the Vimeo forum, as I'm noticing this problem is rampant across multiple videos, multiple website domains, in multiple versions of IE and across multiple operating systems. Something systemic must be up...

Comment: Don't use Vimeo for less than IE9 at this time. It's not even recognizing embed params and I've updated flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the problem was updating the Flash!

See the print with Vimeo above and Youtube below. Before and after upload.

## Before:

[image: Before Upload]

## After:

[image: After Upload]

Comment: This seems to be (unfortunately) the only fix. After a huge discussion with Vimeo staff (https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:68905), it does not seem they do now or plan to ever support outdated versions of Flash. Bummer for the internet audience that does not know how to or hasn't updated their software. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a thread that discusses this problem, they have provided a solution

> In order to fix this, please wrap the following code fragment in player.core.opt.js starting at line 17 character ~316 (in the minified file):
>   d=!!b.canPlayType;if(d){d=new Boolean(d);d.vp6=b.canPlayType('video/x-flv; codecs="vp6"')||false;d.vp8=b.canPlayType('video/webm; codecs="vp8,vorbis"')||false

However, if you're loading this inside a iFrame which I am doing then you'll find that js script is loaded from vimeo's cdn, and so you can't alter it.

http://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:100056